# Get current state of css

Tags: javascript, css

I want to get the current state of css of my whole application at a given moment. The page has many animations and I need to get the css state in a frozen moment.

This is what I have so far, but my page has a height of like 70.000 pixels, so it is inefficient and crashing:

```
const allElements = await document.getElementsByTagName('*');
  let css = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
    const styles = window.getComputedStyle(allElements[i], null);

    css += `${await this.getDomPath(allElements[i])} { \n`;

    if (styles.content) {
      Object.keys(styles).forEach(key => {
        if (isNaN(Number(key))) {
          css += `${key}: ${styles[key]}; \n`;
        }
      });
    }
    css += `}`;
    console.log('css :', css);

 getDomPath(el) {
  var stack = [];
  while (el.parentNode != null) {
    var sibCount = 0;
    var sibIndex = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < el.parentNode.childNodes.length; i++) {
      var sib = el.parentNode.childNodes[i];
      if (sib.nodeName == el.nodeName) {
        if (sib === el) {
          sibIndex = sibCount;
        }
        sibCount++;
      }
    }
    if (el.hasAttribute('id') && el.id != '') {
      stack.unshift(el.nodeName.toLowerCase() + '#' + el.id);
    } else if (sibCount > 1) {
      stack.unshift(el.nodeName.toLowerCase() + ':eq(' + sibIndex + ')');
    } else {
      stack.unshift(el.nodeName.toLowerCase());
    }
    el = el.parentNode;
  }

  let selector = '';
  stack.forEach(element => {
    selector = `${selector} ${element}`;
  });
  return Promise.resolve(selector); // removes the html element
},
```

Comment: Well, you can start by removing the unnecessary promises in that. There are no asynchronous operations there, no need for all that overhead.

Comment: The height of your page in pixels has nothing whatsoever to do with how much work that code has to do, btw. A single element can be 70k pixels tall.

Comment: The following one-liner seems to return all the effective styles of all displayed elements (not including pseudo-elements) with decent performance: `[...document.querySelectorAll('html, body, body *')].map(item => window.getComputedStyle(item))`